# Unable to chat in The Bridge

Tags: support, chat

When I try to chat in The Bridge it says I can't because I've been suspended from the Stack Exchange main network for 359 days. However, if that were the case how come I can post this? Also, I'm currently able to post messages on the Stack Exchange Meta main chatroom without issue.

Also, all other Stack Exchange stuff works fine.

So yeah, it's a bit weird. Anyone know why I can't access The Bridge?

Answer (score 3):

Your account was [banned on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/145550/peter-david-carter) and this is the specific reason why its chat account is banned from *all* rooms on [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Your account can chat on [chat.meta.stackexchange.com](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) because its associated parent account is not banned on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/319383/buddha-peter-d-carter-poulsen).

Comment: So how come I can still chat in Stack Overflow main chat?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen because you are not banned from Stack Overflow. Chat Stack Overflow and Chat Meta Stack Overflow work differently from Chat Stack Exchange

Comment: *I'm not banned from Arqade either*. I was banned from English Language and Usage main site ages ago (for reasons I contest, but that's by the by) and I never got a chat ban before. And that was nothing to do with anything I said in chat, and Oded said the system hasn't changed since then, *in comments that are now deleted (by him or whoever), but we have screenshots of*.

Comment: Actually - I wasn't the one that deleted the comments, but full points for making assumptions.

Comment: @Oded You know what, the above rationale is total bollocks. I've figured out what it was. It's because people in Super User were teaching me about ethical hacking. The Super User chat is the same chat server. This has nothing to do with English Language and Usage whatsoever, at least not directly.